# How to exit a loop inside a functionin Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, return, break

I am trying to **exit a function call when a value is found**, and I can not wrap my head around this.

Using the debugger I've noticed that the `return found;` line makes execution jump to the end of the function, OK... but after that another iteration on the `for` loop is started.

I've tried using break too.

My code is below.

### Edited

I've checked the logic on the debugger, adding a breakpoint on `found = true` and it works fine, so the only thing left is that it should exit properly after that...

```
//  Tree traversal until answer found via answer.id

    function locateAnswer(wholeTree, answerID) {
      var found = false;
      if (wholeTree.answers) { // checks if next_queston is populated first

        for (var i = 0; i < wholeTree.answers.length; ++i) {        
          if (wholeTree.answers[i].id == answerID) {

            console.log("found!");
            found = true;
            return found;       // TRIED break; TOO

          } else {
            for (var j = 0; j < $scope.breadcrumbs.length; ++j) {
              if ($scope.breadcrumbs[j].question == wholeTree.question) {
                // if already exist, we pop elements until it does not exist anymore
                while ($scope.breadcrumbs[j]) {
                  $scope.breadcrumbs.pop();
                }
              }
            }

            // we push the new breadcrumb
            $scope.breadcrumbs.push({ "question": wholeTree.question, "answer": wholeTree.answers[i].answer });

            locateAnswer(wholeTree.answers[i].next_question, answerID);
          }
        }
      }
     //  ALSO TRIED return HERE AFTER break
    };
```

Comment: `return` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`break`](https://codeburst.io/javascript-continue-vs-break-47b5c15cacc6) inside the loop and return statement at the end of the function. Please **updated code**

```
function locateAnswer(wholeTree, answerID) {
      var found = false;
      if (wholeTree.answers) { // checks if next_queston is populated first

        for (var i = 0; i < wholeTree.answers.length; ++i) {        
          if (wholeTree.answers[i].id == answerID) {

            console.log("found!");
            var found = true;

          break;        // TRIED break; TOO

          } else {
            for (var j = 0; j < $scope.breadcrumbs.length; ++j) {
              if ($scope.breadcrumbs[j].question == wholeTree.question) {
                // if already exist, we pop elements until it does not exist anymore
                while ($scope.breadcrumbs[j]) {
                  $scope.breadcrumbs.pop();
                }
              }
            }

            // we push the new breadcrumb
            $scope.breadcrumbs.push({ "question": wholeTree.question, "answer": wholeTree.answers[i].answer });

            locateAnswer(wholeTree.answers[i].next_question, answerID);
          }
        }
      }
     //  ALSO TRIED return HERE AFTER break
 return found;
    };
```

Comment: Tried this, does not work either... Is it something related with the recursion? Am I calling it in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use break instead of return inside the for loop

Comment: Tried this, does not work either... Is it something related with the recursion? Am I calling it in the wrong place?